# Ignore specific warnings that are only raised sometimes

Tags: r, warnings, testthat

One of my tests involves a code that might produce a specific warning.  If this warning appears, I would like to ignore it.  However, if there is any other warning, I would like to catch it as an error.  What is the easiest way to achieve this with `testthat`?

An application would be randomized testing or other situations where it is difficult to determine beforehand whether the input to a function is such that a warning will be raised.

Toy Example:

```
library(testthat)

for (i in 0:100) {
  a <- sample(100, 1) - 5
  result <- (a + 0):(a + 10) / (a + 10):(a + 0)
  result2 <- (log(min(result)))
}
```

Of course, in this toy example it is easy to check whether `result < 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The following works, inspired by looking at `testthat::expect_warning`: Use `testthat::capture_warning` and analyze the warning:

```
library(testthat)

for (i in 0:100) {
  a <- sample(100, 1) - 5
  result <- (a + 0):(a + 10) / (a + 10):(a + 0)
  w <- capture_warnings(result2 <- (log(min(result))))
  if (length(w) > 0) {
    expect_match(w, regexp = "^$|.*NaNs produced.*")
  }
  print(result2)
}
```